# Rails: creating a test website that is not local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

**How is a test site created with Rails 4?**

I'm building a Rails 4 app. I develop locally, have a github repo, and have a live production Heroku site.

Now I want a 'test' or 'dev' site that is on the web, so all the employees working with the app can see features even before they are rolled out.

It sounds like a standard enough issue that I suspect Rails has some built in approach, making use of the "dev", "test, and "production" environment variables.

Comment: Create 2 more Heroku projects, exclusively for "test" and "dev"

Comment: sounds like you want a 'staging' environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku has a methodology for this --

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use standard git mechanics to control the flow. On a web application we develop this really helps us. We have a reasonable sized team and what we do is:

1. Create a feature branch (tools like git-flow can help with keeping standards in your team)
2. When done we push up to our git remote, create a pull request and someone reviews the contribution. Once the changes are good they get merged into master.
3. As part of continuous integration (after our specs are run successfully) we have a simple Jenkins job that clean rebases into the appropriate branch and pushes to the remote.

Everyone has their own flow, but you can use your master branch as development then when you're ready merge/rebase into your other environment branches.

On your destination Rails platform (in my case [Ninefold](http://ninefold.com/), because it's really easy), pick the branch and deploy. On Ninefold as soon as you push to your branch your app is redeployed via a [Post-receive hook](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks).

We configure up the application's environment by passing RAILS_ENV=staging / RAILS_ENV=production, and ensure you have an appropriate (environment).rb file with all the relevant settings for your environment.

Comment: +1 because even though this isn't the a Heroku-centric answer (once you use Heroku, you learn not to go against the grain with them hah) it brings up CI, which is ultimately the way to make a stable long-term staging system. Heroku has some CI add-ons available but I'm not sure whether there is a staging server component or if they are simply a deployment filter (don't deploy if unit tests fail).